# Android: Change APIDemo example AnimateDrawable.java to have a ClickEvent-Handler

Tags: android, events, animation, view

I love the API Demo examples from the Android webpage and used the [AnimateDrawable.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/AnimateDrawable.html-) to
get started with a WaterfallView with several straight falling images which works great. Now I like the images to stop when they are clicked. I found out that Drawables can't handle events so I changed AnimateDrawable and ProxyDrawable to be extended from View instead and added a Click-Event-Listener and Handler on the parent WaterfallView. The animation still works great, but the handler doesn't, probably because in AnimateDrawable the whole canvas is shifted when the drawabled are animated. How can I change that example so that I can implement an event handler? Or is there a way to find out where exactly my AnimateDrawables are in the view?

So the more general question is: *How to add an Event Listener / Handler to an animated View?*

Here are my changes to the example above:

- AnimateView and ProxyView instead of AnimateDrawable and ProxyDrawable
- ProxyView extended from View and all super calls changed to mProxy
- I commented out mutate()
- The context is still the main Activity which is passed down in the constructors
- In the constructors of AnimateView setClickable(true) and setFocusable(true) are called

And here is the important source code of the parent/main WaterfallView:

```
  public class WaterfallView extends View implements OnClickListener {

  private Context mContext;
  // PictureEntry is just a value object to manage the pictures
  private Vector<PictureEntry> pictures = new Vector<PictureEntry>();

  public WaterfallView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  mContext = context;

  pictures.add(new PictureEntry(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_0)));
  pictures.add(new PictureEntry(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_1)));
  pictures.add(new PictureEntry(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_2)));
  pictures.add(new PictureEntry(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_3)));
  pictures.add(new PictureEntry(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_4)));
  pictures.add(new PictureEntry(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_5)));
  pictures.add(new PictureEntry(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_6)));
  pictures.add(new PictureEntry(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_7)));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  if(!setup) {
  for(PictureEntry pic : pictures) pic.setAnimation(createAnimation(pic));
  setup = true;
  }

  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
  for(PictureEntry pic : pictures) pic.getAnimateView().draw(canvas);
  invalidate();
  }

  private Animation createAnimation(PictureEntry picture) {
  Drawable dr = picture.getDrawable();
  dr.setBounds(0, 0, dr.getIntrinsicWidth(), dr.getIntrinsicHeight());
  Animation an = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -1*dr.getIntrinsicHeight(), this.getHeight());
  an.setRepeatCount(-1);
  an.initialize(10, 10, 10, 10);
  AnimateView av = new AnimateView(mContext, dr, an);
  av.setOnClickListener(this);
  picture.setAnimateView(av);
  an.startNow();
  return an;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  Log.i("MyLog", "clicked "+v);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to be clicking widgets(buttons, checkboxes, etc)?  Or do you want to be able to click anywhere?  I think you want the latter.  So in that case you'll need this method:

`@Override`

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // do stuff with your event

}
```

This method is **ONLY** called when the event is **NOT** handled by a view, so I think you may have to remove some of your onClickListener stuff.  Refer to [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) for more info.  And as always, experiment.

Comment: Ho John, thanks for your help. If I use that directly on the WaterfallView it works fine, but I'm also able to click where no pictures are and I don't get information of which picture I clicked. If I put it in the AnimateView it doesn't work unfortunately. Is that because of the canvas shift from the example above? What's the best way to animate a view (within another view)?

Comment: @Daniel: Honestly, I've never done that before.  However, you might try looking here: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/04/animated-views.html